# User account control can not be disabled from command prompt

Tags: command, windows-7-x64, uac, user-account-control

I want to disable UAC on each client computers remotely via an application which executes commands on computer. When I execute the command below:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k %windir%\System32\reg.exe ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k %windir%\System32\reg.exe query  HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD
```

I got this result. 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
    EnableLUA    REG_DWORD    0x0

But when I check UAC manually, I see the UAC is active. What is the reason of this? Can you help to solve this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by restarting the computer after running script.

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k %windir%\System32\reg.exe ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```